# How to find Oracle error log in 11gR2?

Tags: oracle

I am facing issues with Oracle log files. My application inserts data from xml file into Oracle. I started my application last day and went home. It stopped unexpectedly at 8PM. There is no log in application why the insertion stopped.

I want to check Oracle log file to check what exactly the error was and why the Oracle stopped inserting data.

I have log.xml file and multiple *.trc and *.trm file. I don`t know how to start with this.

I just have to check the error that why the Oracle has stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from what maialithar said, you can also check the alert_yourSID.log or the listener.log

Answer (score 0):

You have to open and read your `log.xml` file. Find the date when the error occured and read the messages. Eventually, when you find an error, it can point you to additional `.trc` file. Read it and see what happens.